# clicking on "a" doesn't fire anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I want to build a drop down list with check box options.

I found this very simple example:
http://codepen.io/ElmahdiMahmoud/pen/hlmri

I am trying to make exactly like it. so I copied and pasted the code like this:

#### aspx code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestDropdownChecklist.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <dl class="dropdown">

        <dt>
            <a href="#">
                <span class="hida">Select</span>
                <p class="multiSel"></p>
            </a>
        </dt>

        <dd>
            <div class="mutliSelect">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Apple" />Apple</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Blackberry" />Blackberry</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="HTC" />HTC</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Sony Ericson" />Sony Ericson</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Motorola" />Motorola</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Nokia" />Nokia</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </dd>

    </dl>
</body>
</html>
```

but when I click on the `select`, nothing happens.

please tell me I am doing something wrong? or I should have done something I didn't do?

#### js.js

```
/*
    Dropdown with Multiple checkbox select with jQuery - May 27, 2013
    (c) 2013 @ElmahdiMahmoud
    license: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*/

$(".dropdown dt a").on('click', function () {
    $(".dropdown dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
});

$(".dropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function () {
    $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
});

function getSelectedValue(id) {
    return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
}

$(document).bind('click', function (e) {
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
});


$('.mutliSelect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {

    var title = $(this).closest('.mutliSelect').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
        title = $(this).val() + ",";

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
        $('.multiSel').append(html);
        $(".hida").hide();
    }
    else {
        $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
        var ret = $(".hida");
        $('.dropdown dt a').append(ret);

    }
});
```

Comment: This is not expected from experienced user, __Post you js script code here.__

Comment: You'll need to show the code in `js.js`, otherwise we have no idea why clicking the `<a>` should do anything

Comment: @Satpal I copied the js

Comment: @lan I copied the js now.

Comment: Your JS is trying to bind events to elements that don't exist yet. Move your script to right before `</body>`

Comment: You should use [document-ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler, bind your event inside [document-ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your **js.js** file is in the `<head>` of your document, it is running before anything in the `<body>` exists. You have 2 options:

1. move `<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>` just before the closing `</body>` tag so it runs last
2. Wrap the contents of **js.js** in `$(document).ready(function(){ /*your code here*/ });` so it doesn't run until the document is loaded.  Like this:

   ```
   /*
   Dropdown with Multiple checkbox select with jQuery - May 27, 2013
   (c) 2013 @ElmahdiMahmoud
   license: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
   */
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".dropdown dt a").on('click', function () {
           $(".dropdown dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
       });

       $(".dropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function () {
           $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
       });

   function getSelectedValue(id) {
           return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
       }

       $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
           var $clicked = $(e.target);
           if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
       });


       $('.mutliSelect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {
           var title = $(this).closest('.mutliSelect').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
           title = $(this).val() + ",";

           if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
               var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
               $('.multiSel').append(html);
               $(".hida").hide();
           }
           else {
               $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
               var ret = $(".hida");
               $('.dropdown dt a').append(ret);
           }
       });
   });
   ```